# Lucene Hebrew analyzer

Tags: lucene, hebrew, stemming

Does anybody know whether one exists?

I've been googling this for monthes...

Thanks

Comment: It's time the open source community makes one.  It seems to me that true stemming is _very_ difficult, to the point of requiring vast amounts of manpower, but that some basic stemming is possible, and perhaps a minimal stemmer is better than zero stemming.  I'll probably start working on this on my own.  If anyone is interested, please contact me.

Comment: ...And as a first step, I'll try to use hspell(3)'s enumeration.  It's effectively a ready stemmer!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Update**
[HebMorph](https://github.com/synhershko/HebMorph)

Out of curiosity sparked by your question, I contacted Itamar Syn-Hershko who was active on Lucene mailing lists about a year ago when he was working on a Hebrew analyzer for Lucene. I asked him if he completed his analyzer. Here are some relevant bits from his response:

> To make a long story short, no I
>   didn't. There is no decent free /
>   open-source Hebrew analyzer for
>   Lucene, that I can say for sure. I'm
>   not sure what is your background on
>   the subject, but believe me when I say
>   there is no easy way of doing this; it
>   might be also the Lucene isn't built
>   for Hebrew searches, but I do agree a
>   solution has to be given. Granted, the
>   safest way to index and search Hebrew
>   texts is to use a specialized stemmer,
>   and integration with Lucene is not the
>   easiest even after you've done this.
>   There are a few very good solutions
>   for Hebrew search in the market, only
>   one that I know of is using Lucene in
>   it's core; I've recently tried
>   contacting them, no response yet...

The commercial product based on Lucene that is mentioned is called ATTIVIO and [the ATTIVIO website](http://www.attivio.com/active-intelligence/aie-platform.html) does claim to have Hebrew support. At [SIGTRS (Hebrew Text Retrieval interest group)](http://www.sigtrs.org/), there has been some [discussion regarding ATTIVIO](http://www.google.com/#q=ATTIVIO+site%3Asigtrs.org) that claims it is Lucene based.

So, apparently, it is possible to create a decent Hebrew analyzer for Lucene, but there is no free analyzer available at this time.

Comment: Hi, I finally got the time to start working on one, and so far it looks promising. See: http://www.code972.com/blog/hebmorph/. Itamar.

Answer (score 0):

dtsearch has a hebrew stemming plugin call "pensim".
It appears to be developed by "wizcomtech.com".